# HTML/CSS - Make navigation bar height match body

Tags: html, css

I have a school project and I'm more or less done except for one last thing. I have searched stackoverflow and various sites found when googling with lots of answers, which I have tried but with no luck.

I want to make the navigation bar match the height of my body. I have tried with height: 100%; and min-height: 100%;. It works when I set height to exactly what the current height of the body is e.g: 
body = 530.88px but height: inherit; doesn't work.

```
#nav_bar {
height: 530.88px;
}
```

But I want an adaptive height to the browser window.

CSS - snippet

```
#body_wrap {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#nav_bar {  
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#nav_bar_logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block; 
}
#nav_bar_logo img {
     display: block;
     max-height: 90%;
     max-width: 90%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
```

Full HTML: https://hastebin.com/bipecofowe.xml 
Full CSS:  https://hastebin.com/edepohigoh.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the navigation height to cover whole `body` (page) you can do :

```
body,html{ min-height: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

but if you wish to set the nav height dynamic to body's height you could use a bit of jQuery and js :

```js
$(function(){
  // Get body height
  var bodyHeight = $('body').height()

  $('nav').css({
    'height' : bodyHeight,
  });
})
```

```css
nav{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>

  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Also if you with the body to have full height of the current view port you can do this :

`#nav_bar { height: 100vh }`

Comment: The course is restricted to html5 and css but I'm still saving the answer for future referense. This: body,html{ min-height: 100%; height: 100%;} did the trick for me, thanks.